# how to filter or alter html on a remote web server?

Tags: javascript, php, web, lamp

I was wondering if there was a minimalistic way to alter a customer's web content on the fly without having to touch their code on their server?

In the example below hopefully makes some sense of what I'm asking:

```
1. A customer goes to a webpage like toysrus.net
2. That server serves up html content as usual.
3. My web filtering server then takes that content and alters it.
4. The finished product is now altered (in green)
5. The customer never sees the original content, they get the new content.
```

[image: Filtering Web Content]

In this example I add style="" to all of the  tags and alt="hi" to the  tags.  So my question is if this is possible without altering their code on their server and just somehow send that data to my server first ? Or use JS to alter the page or something ?  Just wondering if anyone has some ideas or insight .?

Comment: You can probably use curl to get the html then edit it there and produce an html file. I know that this can be done on the fly with a chrome extention or something similar because I saw it done before but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Maybe an iframe and some javascript can do the job?

Comment: If they really want to visit `toysrus.net` they might have to get in quick … ;)

Comment: Does it matter which browser? I believe there are addons to do that.

Comment: Should have no requirements for the end user and not iframe but Yeah I was thinking JS would need to be added to their site or something